# Bootstrap3 Datetimepicker enabledHours not working

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, datetimepicker

I need to enable only some hrs ( 8 am, 9am, 10am, 1pm, 2pm, 3pm) on my datetimepicker. Here my code.
Thanks in advance. :)

```
 $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            inline: true,
            sideBySide: true,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY h a',
            disabledHours: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
            enabledHours: [8, 9, 10, 13, 14, 15]
        });
    });
```

Comment: In my version of the plugin, the property has another name than the current and it accepts a string like this: hoursDisabled: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24'. No idea why they've changed it (I see documentation now), you can try it if you want.

Comment: try using disabledTimeIntervals(), but it will work for current day only.